# Data Masking in Azure data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, etl, data-masking, azure-postgresql

We are using Azure Data factory to move data from Source like Azure SQL and Azure Postgres to destination as Azure data lake.There is some sensitive data which needs to be masked.
Is it possible to have data masking in Azure Data factory during transformation phase only?

Thanks! in advance

Comment: masked in data lake? to do transformation _in_ ADF you need to be using data flows. Is that what you are using?

Comment: Yes we are using Data flow in ADF and as per requirement we should be able to mask data during data flow.

Comment: Good point below-does the mask need to be reversible?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage on Cryptographic functions of the source DB and use it in the SELECT statement to get encrypted data into the data lake. If you use a reversible function you can decrypt later on.
You can also mask the data using SQL function (e.g selecting only a substring of a sensitive column) but then it won't be reversible (same thing if you leverage Data Masking on the Azure SQL DB)

Here the [Cryptographic functions for Azure SQL DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cryptographic-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is a option of dynamic data masking in the portal where you have deployed the database. You can go there and select the table and column to mask your data

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/dynamic-data-masking-overview?view=azuresql

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).